# Install Windows 10 on external USB attached HDD - not bootable

Tags: windows-10, installation, usb-storage

I am trying to install a fresh Windows 10 onto a number of 2.5 inch HDDs.

I have downloaded the Windows 10 iso.

I have a caddy that can hold the 2.5 inch drives.

The reading I have done indicates I need to use a tool like “Hasleo wintoUSB” to install Windows on the external USB attached drive.

Now I can install Windows 10 on the external drive using the “Windows to Go” option in WintoUSB. The resulting installation will boot but only when the disk is in the USB caddy – when I move the disk into the PC, the PC cannot boot from this drive. All I see is an almost completely blank screen with a flashing underscore cursor in the top left-hand corner of the screen.

If I use the “windows installation USB” option in WintoUSB, this will create a bootable drive that can be used to boot a machine and install Windows 10 on a different disk. I don’t want this I want to create bootable Windows 10 drives that can be installed internally in other PCs.

So, can I run WintoUSB on machine 1 to create a Windows 10 system disk on a USB attached drive, then move that drive to machine 2 and boot from it when attached as an internal drive? Or is there other software that will do this? Or do I need to install Windows in a different way to multiple target disks?

Comment: *can I run WintoUSB on machine 1 to create a Windows 10 system disk on a USB attached drive, then move that drive to machine 2 and boot from it when attached as an internal drive?* No, you can't. Any software allowing installation in external drive use "hacks".

Comment: You can't use windows-to-go for this, since it disables internal drives. You should be able to boot to the win10 iso and install to the USB-attached hard drive. You may need to be careful of whether it installs in UEFI or Legacy mode though, as whatever computer boots from it later will need to be in the same mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this installation in a more "conventional" way.

1. I put an "old" HDD inside the computer
2. I installed Windows 10 on the internal drive using a USB drive that had been setup using the Windows media creation tool.
3. I used DiskGenius to clone the new Windows 10 system on the internal drive to a USB-attached disk caddy - then copied the new system multiple times to target drives in the caddy.

This approach worked and I have tested the clone-output disks in the target machines and Windows boots up fine.